# iPhone: How to create title bar like in Google+ stream?

Tags: iphone, ios, google-plus

I'm about to create an app with the same technology like the Google+ app. I want to reproduce the "stream"-viewcontroller.

Currently i've set up a scrollview with paging and pagecontrol, but I can't get how the bar under the navigationbar in the Google+-app is created. It shows the titles of the current page and the pages to the left and right. It also has a zoom-effect that zoom in at the current visible pagetitle.

Anyone has any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it would be to create your VC, throw a scrollview in it whose x, y and width are the same as your backing view, but whose height is the height of your backing view minus however high you want your titlebar to be. Create a separate view for that. Your paging scrollview will work fine for the content area.

For your titlebar, you'll probably just set up some `CABasicAnimations` and keep some images off screen, sliding them around as you see fit, or what-have-you. This is one approach you can use.

Comment: Thanks jer for your answer! I'll let you know if I got it right or not later (will mark your answer as "accepted answer" then).